# ADBannerView Issues

Tags: swift, adbannerview

I have this code on all my `viewcontroller` pages to control my `AdBanner` across multiple pages. It works correctly on the last version on my app but for some reason in this update I'm working on I don't think my app is calling either the `bannerViewDidLoadAd` or `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` functions. Also I am getting this error when I change pages a lot. `

> "WARNING: More than 10 instances of ADBannerView or ADInterstitialView
>   currently exist. This is a misuse of the iAd API, and ad performance
>   will suffer as a result. This message is printed only once."

` Is there something I am missing? Thanks

```
// Ad controller

var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()
var screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
var adBannerHeight: CGFloat = 50
@IBOutlet var constOne: NSLayoutConstraint!

func appdelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    UIiAd.delegate = nil
    UIiAd.removeFromSuperview()
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    UIiAd.alpha = 1
    adBannerHeight = 50
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    constOne.constant = 58
    print("ad loaded")
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    UIiAd.alpha = 0
    adBannerHeight = 0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    constOne.constant = 8
    print("error")
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    UIiAd.delegate = self
    UIiAd = self.appdelegate().UIiAd
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight - adBannerHeight , 0, 0)
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)

}

// End of Ad Controller
```

Comment: So I feel like I fixed the issue but I have my doubts. I replaced all my code with 1 line 'self.canDisplayBannerAds = true' It seems to be the solution but I don't know how it reacts. It is hard to tell in the simulator if every page loads a new ad or if this is a shared iAd banner. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this code:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    UIiAd.delegate = nil
    UIiAd.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

To:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
     UIiAd.removeFromSuperview()
     UIiAd.delegate = nil
}
```

Comment: I just get this message. Nil cannot be assigned to type 'ADBannerView'

Comment: @ElectricTiger just try remove UIiAd = nil

Comment: no difference unfortunately. Would it help if I told you I also have this code in AppDelegate.swift? var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()